# xslt 2.0 collection and copy issue- not copying full file

Tags: xslt-2.0

using xslt 2.0.
 Have a couple xmls 
 - i m trying to merge using xslt 2.0 and collection function 
but it is copying only some of it and leaving the combined xml file not well formed.
Could this be a timeout issue, I did not think so since it takes only couple seconds to throw out error.
or a collection memory issue?
If i take just 1 file too, it is copying only most of the stuff but not all.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Example:

```
<Response xmlns:a="http://example.com">
   <FormInstance id="FORM1">
      <element1>111-22-1122</element1>
</FormInstance>
   <FormInstance id="FORM2">
      <element1>111-22-1123</element1>
</FormInstance>
   <FormInstance id="FORM3">
      <element1>111-22-1124</element1>
</FormInstance>
</Response>
```

XSLT here:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:a="http://example.com" xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
     <xsl:template match="/">
        <Response>
            <xsl:for-each select="collection('.?select=*.xml')">
            <xsl:for-each select="/Response">
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"></xsl:copy-of>
            </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </Response>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't see how a template matching on `/` creating a single result `Response` element and then doing all other processing to populate that element can result in something not well-formed. You might want to post minimal but complete samples of XML inputs, XML result you get and the one you want.

Comment: sorry if i am not being clear. i am 2 or more xmls like the example i have above and needing to take all FormInstance elements from all different xmls merge them into 1 xml under <Response> tag as below. <Response><FormInstance id="Form1">....</FormInstance>...</Response>

Comment: And which is the result you get instead? Your code looks like a rather convoluted attempt (I would simply use `<xsl:template name="main"><Response><xsl:copy-of select="collection('?select=*.xml')/*/FormInstance"/></Response></xsl:template>`) but in the end I think the nested for-each and copy-of should give the same result.

Comment: So, when i use my xslt code, it copies most forminstance nodes from the second xml but does not copy all/ leaves some elements half way for unknown reason and hence makes xml half complete/ not well formed.

Comment: Well, as said, "You might want to post minimal but complete samples of XML inputs, XML result you get and the one you want", to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: sure sir, problem is it is sensitive data, so, i need to sample it up and send it over.

Comment: finally, i had to read xmls and store in a variable and use that variable for more transformation, thanks for all your help